# Scaling issue in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am using scale to make an easy effect on a background-img, 
it works as expected on chrome, safari.

But not on Firefox.

http://u2854332.fsdata.se/

You see the problem that it is leaving a empty white margin on the right.

/ Martin

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a white margin on Firefox + Mac OSX mountain lion.

General firefox issue:

Define a width first, like:

```
.className { 
width: 100%;
yourWidth : value;
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: THANKS! It must have been another property somewhere bugging me. Probably an overflow-property somewhere. The problem is gone for me ni.